# Blazor components: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods or statements

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a blazor project and am adding a new component. I've got a bunch of other components already and they are building/compiling fine but when I added this new component it seems like it thinks its not actually a .razor file? I'm honestly baffled.

I've tried `dotnet clean`, `dotnet restore`, and `dotnet tool restore` and nothing is fixing this. It also has the same failure in CI which leads me to believe its a problem with the application code itself, and not some kind of cache issue.

I'm only posting the code block since it seems like the only relevant thing here but can post the whole component if that would be helpful.

The build errors are as follows:

```bash
22>[project-path]/Shared/Components/Staff/BorrowerTasks/TaskStatusDropdown.razor(45,29): Error CS0116 : A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods or statements
22>[project-path]/Shared/Components/Staff/BorrowerTasks/TaskStatusDropdown.razor(48,40): Error CS0116 : A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods or statements
22>[project-path]/Shared/Components/Staff/BorrowerTasks/TaskStatusDropdown.razor(50,29): Error CS0116 : A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods or statements
22>[project-path]/Shared/Components/Staff/BorrowerTasks/TaskStatusDropdown.razor(50,29): Error CS0115 : '<invalid-global-code>.OnInitialized()': no suitable method found to override
```

```
@using Lower.Lending.Interface.DataTypes
@using Lower.Lending.Interface.DTOs
@using Lower.Shared.Collections

<div class="task-status-dropdown">
    <LowerDropdown Label="Change Task Status">
        <ButtonContent>
            <LowerParagraph Size="LowerParagraph.Sizes.XS">@TaskDto.Status.GetEnumMemberValue()</LowerParagraph>
            @if (TaskDto.Note is not null)
            {
                <LowerParagraph Variant="LowerParagraph.Variants.Italic"
                                Size="LowerParagraph.Sizes.XS">@TaskDto.Note</LowerParagraph>
            }
        </ButtonContent>
        <DropdownContent>
            <LowerDropdownGroup>
                <LowerDropdownLabel>
                    STATUS
                </LowerDropdownLabel>
                @if (TaskDto.Status is not ConditionTaskStatus.Completed)
                {
                    <LowerDropdownItemButton Label="Complete"
                                             OnClick="@(() => OnStatusChange(ConditionTaskStatus.Completed))">
                        Complete
                    </LowerDropdownItemButton>
                }
                @else
                {
                    <LowerDropdownItemButton Label="Incomplete"
                                             OnClick="@(() => OnStatusChange(ConditionTaskStatus.Incomplete))">
                        Incomplete
                    </LowerDropdownItemButton>
                }
            </LowerDropdownGroup>
        </DropdownContent>
    </LowerDropdown>
</div>

@code
{

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public ConditionTaskDto TaskDto { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public Action<ConditionTaskStatus> OnStatusChange { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        if (TaskDto.Status is ConditionTaskStatus.Deleted)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("A task's status cannot be changed once it has been deleted");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove all the code (empty `@code` block) and make the HTML just some static data. Is the compiler able to build a valid component that can be rendered?

Comment: Weird. `<invalid-global-code>.OnInitialized()` - could there be a bracket or something out of place somewhere not in the screen cap you posted?

Comment: Also, is `null!` valid? I thought the `!` was a non-null assertion operator but...it's null?

Comment: @Nikki9696 `null!` is valid. It's saying "I know this property is not assigned to by the ctor, but I also know that the code that creates the instance will set it." This is/was a common workaround for client types instantiated by e.g. deserialization libraries, ORMs, etc...

Comment: You can't name a variable "Task"

Comment: @Santiago I had high hopes that changing the variable name would work since I forgot about the system Task type...but unfortunately I'm getting the same error

Comment: @HH sorry about that - I added the full file

Comment: @Nikki9696 I don't think there's any missing brackets - I edited the question with my full component code so you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `@else` with just `else`. Razor doesn't seem to like it.